# C# avoid scrolling data received via serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port, continuous

I am receiving continuous data through a serial connection to a windows form. The displayed info shows correct but it scrolls while being displayed. I'm trying to figure out how to show this information on 1 line and 1 position and update as the information changes on the same line. For example: 1 would just change to 2 in the same position instead of 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2. I'm just using the typical - string msg = comPort.ReadLine(); because ReadExisting(); brings the data in choppy.

Comment: Your question really isn't clear ! if you are stroing the incoming data from serial port to a string, the string will not append the data, but get the newest data you read. so : string msg = comPort.ReadLine(); will store the last read. Not the whole data !!
so you have to filter the data if that is your problem, or please describe more .

Comment: So if the first readLine() returns "1 1 1 1 1 1 1" you want to display "1 1 1 1 1 1 1", and if the next line returns "2 2 2 2 2" you want to erase the 1's and show the 2's?

Comment: no, when you step on your digital bathroom scale. It updates the existing digits but doesn't scroll across the screen. That's what I'm trying to achieve. Instead of 1 ,1, 1 then change to 2, 2, 2. I'm looking for a single 1 then update to a single 2.

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. I'll take a bag of nickels to the head for this one. Sorry the question was vague.